# Captcha and captcha text overflows the dialog, on Ask Question page

Tags: bug, user-interface, asking-questions, captcha

I asked a question on MSO a few seconds ago, and was presented with a CAPTCHA that sprawled out of the box:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Can we fix that?

Comment: The CAPTCHA box ends where the text ends. I don't see a problem?

Comment: @Nai54 No it doesn't, the text and reCAPTCHA part poke out the side of the box.  You might not be able to see the overflowing text because it's dark.  Do you have a similar screenshot?